# Sort promises on resolve/reject

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to spawn several task which returns a Promise. 
I would like to get back an Iterator or an Observable which orders
the Promises based on the order of their completion (regardless if rejected or resolved).

I would like to use this operator to go over those Promises and stop when I find the right one.
What the right one is depends on the usecase.

Thanks,
Dieter

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your setup and the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "go over them and stop"? Can you give an example of a function that determines "the right one"?

Comment: why no parallize this?  How will you *stop*?

Comment: I currently have any code to show. I have a list of tasks which run parallel and are potential costly. I would like to iterate over these promises but in the order when they are resolved or rejected. E.g. there are promises p1, p2 and p3. Behind each promise is a long running background task. Now I would like to iterate over the tasks. But lets assume the task behind p3 resolves first. I would like to get the promise as first in my iteration over the promises. Then the next one which finishes (or gets rejected) and os on.